# Only get the first row while doing a leftjoin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to limit the result while doing a leftjoin?

*(Laravel 4.2) - Querybuilder*

I've got the following query with laravel's querybuilder:

```
    DB::table('part')
      ->leftjoin('model', 'model.model_id', '=', 'part.model_id')
      ->leftjoin('make',  'model.make_id',  '=', 'make.make_id')
      ->leftJoin('photo', 'photo.part_id',  '=', 'part.part_id')
      ->select( 'part.part_id',
                'part.model_id',
                'make.desc   as make_desc',
                'model.desc  as model_desc',
                'photo.local as local_img',
                'photo.cdn   as cdn_img')
      ->take(8)->get();
```

Every part has more then 4 photos, but i only want the first photo to be included in the join. The problem is that when i use this query, i get 8 part objects (results). But the 8 results are not 8 parts, but 2 parts. This query creates 4 of the same part objects, with the only difference being the photo (the join includes every photo).

I tried things like:

```
 ->select( '(photo.local LIMIT 1) as local_img',
           '(photo.cdn LIMIT 1) as cdn_img')
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried to do raw query's. Also i tried to use the '->take(1)' in a leftjoin closure, like this:

```
->leftjoin('photo', function($q){
    $q->on('photo', 'photo.part_id',  '=', 'part.part_id')->take(1);
});
```

But this is not possible.

I`m searching for a solution to only include the first photo row in a leftjoin.

Edit: Following up on mgrueter's answer. I know that a groupby would do the trick, but this makes the query very slow. So i want to do it in a different way so the query doesn't get to slow.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is groupby. I would try using group by on part.part_id

Answer (score 0):

Group the results by 'part.id':

```
DB::table('part')
  ->leftjoin('model', 'model.model_id', '=', 'part.model_id')
  ->leftjoin('make',  'model.make_id',  '=', 'make.make_id')
  ->leftJoin('photo', 'photo.part_id',  '=', 'part.part_id')
  ->select( 'part.part_id',
            'part.model_id',
            'make.desc   as make_desc',
            'model.desc  as model_desc',
            'photo.local as local_img',
            'photo.cdn   as cdn_img')
  ->group_by('part.part_id')
  ->take(8)->get();
```

And also order the results by 'photo.created' or whatever column you have to determine, which is the first photo.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what i am doing right now. But i really don`t want to do that, because it makes the query very slow. (There are a lot of parts to groupby)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the only solution, besides doing 2 queries (1 to get all the models, parts and makes, 1 to get the photos for the previous found part_ids) - which is probably the better solution if you're worried that group_by is slow.

Comment: Or you could use "explain" to figure out if better/different indexes could help you out with the performance of the group_by

Comment: Have you tried using Eloquent in Laravel. Relationships (in Eloquent) seems to be a good solution to solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input mgrueter. Unfortunately the database is old, and used in a lot of projects. So indexing has its risks which i am not willing to take. I am now creating 2 queries, like you suggested, 1 for the parts and 1 for the photos, so i can check the speed-difference.

Comment: @marqs: Yes, at first i used eloquent. But the Part model is huge. It has a lot of relationships and attributes i don`t need in this particular case. So doing it with eloquent makes it even more slow.

Comment: @MaHo: Ok. I forgot to add using Eager Loading but I guess you have tried that aswell. Then I would go with mgrueter's suggestion running two queries.